# Snowflake External Table DDL

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am aware that we will not be able to get the DDL for the external table using GET_DDL function in snowflake. Is there any workaround to get the DDL( Create Statement) for the external table in snowflake?

Answer (score 0):

You can get pretty close using the `DESC EXTERNAL TABLE` command and then leveraging the `expression` column to then build at least some of the DDL, but there is no workaround to get the direct DDL statement that was used.  In addition, the `SHOW EXTERNAL TABLE` command will provide the external files being leveraged.